# Shared classes between namespaces, how to distribute them?

Tags: c#, .net, libraries, namespace

Some time ago I read from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017SWPNO) that namespaces inside libraries should be distributed in a way that inner namespaces have more concrete classes than their parent namespaces. We can find an example of this inside the namespace `System.Net`, where we can find the class [WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). This class has a higher abstraction level than [Socket](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) which is inside the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace (in fact, `WebClient` uses `Socket`).

My question is, how about all those classes used by the parent and descendant namespaces? In which namespace should I put them? Should I create a new different one called something like `Parent.Shared` and import them from `Parent`, from `Parent.Child` and from `Parent.Child.GrandChild`?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943613/net-shared-classes-between-namespaces-how-to-distribute-them "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat Ok, I understand, so what can I do in those cases, is it there a link or something to transfer a question from one site to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are a mechanism to show a correlation between classes. Classes within a namespace should be related to each other and the namespace name should give an indication of the commonality between the classes.
For example, all classes within the `System.Net` namespace are networking related classes.

This suggests that it is best to look at namespace names as if they give an organization like `library.topic.subtopic`.

Suppose you have the following namespaces

```
library.topic1
library.topic1.subtopic1a
library.topic1.subtopic1b
library.topic2
```

It is to be expected that classes in `subtopic1a` represent more concrete/detailed concepts than classes in `topic1`. That means that it would be strange to see a class in `subtopic1a` referencing a class in `topic1`, but it would be perfectly normal to see references to classes in `subtopic1b` or in `topic2`. Namespaces are *not* so hierarchical that you can only refer to classes in "lower levels".